# How to tackle a situation when my flowmeter totalizer resetted to zero after reaching to its final value?

Tags: sql-server, grafana, opc

I am making a consumption dashboard which will display every 24hrs of consumtions, i am logging data into MSSQL using an OPC server and using Grafan to display. My query is working on time range using difference of  minimum and maximum value it is is working fine but the problem comes up when my flowmeter resetted to zero after reaching to its max value. How can we deal with such scenarios so that i have the right value ?

Comment: Consumable sample data, expected results, and your attempt(s) will help us help you here.

Comment: You'd typically use something like `Usage = (PresentRead - PreviousRead) + CASE WHEN PreviousRead > PresentRead THEN POWER(10, NumberOfDigits) ELSE 0 END`, or if you have an actual flag for the meter rollover then you can use this which is more robust than assuming a rollover if the present read is lower than the previous. As requested above though, some sample data to show exactly how your data is structured would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you storing data at a specific time interval into your data table (if so do you ever a significant difference in flow rates) or is it storing based on compression deviation? @GarethD I think that's a good equation if the data is stored based on compression deviation.